# Scilab Error: Need to install legacy Java SE 6 runtime

Tags: install, catalina, java

Scilab v6.0.2 is downloaded from the [official website](https://www.scilab.org/download/6.0.2) and installed, but it cannot be opened with the error:

> To open "this Java application" you need to install the legacy Java SE 6 runtime.

I follow instructions in "More info" and on the Internet to download [Java from Apple](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_GB), but Java cannot be installed because `"A newer version of this package is already installed"`, shown below:

[image]

My MacOS is Catalina v.10.15.3. 
How can I escape this loop?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I detect possible discrepancies in the requirements. I would *guess* that if the Scilab software requires a version of java this old, then the Scilab software will not be compatible with Catalina. However, the [system requirements](https://www.scilab.org/download/system-requirements) state Scilab needs Java 8. This is one discrepancy. Also, note the system requirements do not include Catalina. You may need to add Mojave as a second macOS to get Scilab to run. Fortunately, this is not difficult to do, provided your Mac has enough space and is not to new to run Mojave.

Comment: I've had a similar problem with another software that relies on Java. The workaround is to change some capabilities in a config file for your current java installation. Maybe it will work for you as well, see instructions here: https://www.awareim.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=48828#p48828

Comment: The official website has also a newer version, Scilab 6.1.0 - I presume this one needs java8.

Comment: @Lizzan That helps. Thank you all guys ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried downloading Scilab and it runs fine on my Catalina, where I've done the steps below to get another Java application to run.

Download and install a recent version of the Oracle JDK, like Java SE 13 from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html#JDK13

Then open Terminal (it's in Applications/Utilities) and write

```
cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
```

and press Enter. This changes the working directory to where the Java Virtual Machines are installed. Then do

```
ls
```

to get a list of the installed versions. Enter the Contents directory of the one you're using by writing something like

```
cd jdk-13.0.2.jdk/Contents/
```

Replace the version numbers if you have a different Java version installed.

Open Info.plist in any text editor (if you want to do that from Finder instead of Terminal, write `open .` to open the current folder) and search for these lines:

```
<key>JVMCapabilities</key>
 <array>
  <string>CommandLine</string>
 </array>
```

Replace those with these lines

```
<key>JVMCapabilities</key>
 <array>
  <string>JNI</string>
  <string>BundledApp</string>
  <string>WebStart</string>
  <string>Applets</string>
  <string>CommandLine</string>
 </array>
```

and save the file. Then try opening Scilab again.

Sources: https://crunchify.com/os-x-mavericks-eclipse-java-issue/
and https://www.awareim.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=48828#p48828